# SQL Plus Subquery

Tags: sql, database, subquery

Using SQL Plus

Need help with the following:
A summary of sales for any given day, categorized by package type (i.e., the total sales written on the specified day for each package subscribed to by customers, not bills paid). This report should give details about each package type, the package price, the number of packages sold, and then the total sales amount for that package. Once again, remember that this is going to be a date driven report.

```
SET ECHO ON

SPOOL C:\CIS336\InfoMiners\Week7\Final\InfoMiners_Week7_Task5_FinalSpool.txt

SET LINESIZE 120
SET PAGESIZE 45
SET FEEDBACK 1

-- CIS-336 Online
-- XXXXX XXXXX
-- InfoMiners Week 7 - Task 5 - Reports
-- april 15, 2012


-- DROP Table Statements

DROP TABLE package_guide CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE employee CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE customer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE cust_survey CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE bill_info CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE package CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE channel CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE program CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE ratings CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE network_supplier CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;


-- CREATE Table Statements

CREATE TABLE network_supplier
(
supplier_id VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT pk_supplier_id PRIMARY KEY,
supplier_name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR2(17) NOT NULL,
state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
zip_code NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
contact_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
contact_phone VARCHAR2(14) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ratings
(
rating_code VARCHAR2(17) CONSTRAINT pk_rating_code PRIMARY KEY,
rating_description VARCHAR2(70)
);

CREATE TABLE program
(
program_id NUMBER(17) CONSTRAINT pk_program_id PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL,
supplier_id VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES network_supplier(supplier_id),
length NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR2(30),
type VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
rating_code VARCHAR2(17) REFERENCES ratings(rating_code)
);

CREATE TABLE channel
(
channel_id VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT pk_channel_id PRIMARY KEY,
ch_number NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
customer_count NUMBER(30) NOT NULL,
supplier_id VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES network_supplier(supplier_id),
show_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE package
(
package_id VARCHAR2(2) CONSTRAINT pk_package_id PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
cost NUMBER(5) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bill_info
(
acct_num NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT pk_acct_num PRIMARY KEY,
balance NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
due_date DATE NOT NULL,
acct_current NUMBER(1),
package_id VARCHAR2(2) REFERENCES package(package_id)
);

CREATE TABLE cust_survey
(
survey_id VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT pk_survey_id PRIMARY KEY,
fav_channel VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
months_paid NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE customer
(
customer_id NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT pk_customer_id PRIMARY KEY,
active_date DATE NOT NULL,
cancel_date DATE,
cancel_reason NUMBER(1),
first_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
zip_code NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
phone_num NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
acct_num NUMBER(10) REFERENCES bill_info(acct_num) NOT NULL,
survey_id VARCHAR2(20) REFERENCES cust_survey(survey_id) NOT NULL,
package_id VARCHAR2(2) REFERENCES package(package_id) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employee
(
emp_num NUMBER(11) CONSTRAINT pk_emp_num PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
emp_phone NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE package_guide
(
package_id REFERENCES package(package_id) NOT NULL,
channel_id REFERENCES channel(channel_id) NOT NULL,
program_id REFERENCES program(program_id) NOT NULL
);


-- INSERT Statements

-- Data for network_supplier Table (4 Records)

INSERT INTO network_supplier (supplier_id, supplier_name, address, city, state, zip_code, contact_name, contact_phone)
VALUES (1, 'NBC', '10880 Wilshire Blvd #1200', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', 90057, 'XXXXX XXXXX', '(XXX) XXX-XXXX' );

INSERT INTO network_supplier (supplier_id, supplier_name, address, city, state, zip_code, contact_name, contact_phone)
VALUES (2, 'ABC', '111 Hollywood Blvd.', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', 90046, 'Jack Carverisi', '(XXX) XXX-XXXX' );

INSERT INTO network_supplier (supplier_id, supplier_name, address, city, state, zip_code, contact_name, contact_phone)
VALUES (3, 'FOX', '10960 Wilshire Blvd', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', 90057, 'Janis Carmikel', '(XXX) XXX-XXXX' );

INSERT INTO network_supplier (supplier_id, supplier_name, address, city, state, zip_code, contact_name, contact_phone)
VALUES (4, 'WARNER', '3701 W Oak St.', 'Burbank', 'CA', 91501, 'Simon Philips', '(XXX) XXX-XXXX' );


-- Data for ratings Table (7 Records)

INSERT INTO ratings (rating_code, rating_description)
VALUES ('TV-Y', 'All Children');

INSERT INTO ratings
VALUES ('TV-Y7', 'Directed to Older Children');

INSERT INTO ratings
VALUES ('TV-Y7-FV', 'Directed to Older Children - Fantasy Viol
```

Already Tried:
different variations of select statements but I don't understand using sub queries to fully get the select statement to work.

Read more: SQL Plus Homework Question - JustAnswer http://www.justanswer.com/computer-programming/6j1qs-sql-plus-homework-question.html#ixzz1sA4U5tTz

Comment: @ adrian vona : what is the question?

Comment: I need a query that as able to do the following:

A summary of sales for any given day, categorized by package type (i.e., the total sales written on the specified day for each package subscribed to by customers, not bills paid). This report should give details about each package type, the package price, the number of packages sold, and then the total sales amount for that package. Once again, remember that this is going to be a date driven report.

Comment: @ Adrian Vona : Question, in current form, is too broad to answer.  What you need is `order by` and `group by` .